# Twitter Bootstrap accordion group item with no content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make an accordion with only a few items that expand with child elements and 2 items that do not have child elements that would close anything that is open.

I have a [fiddle setup here](http://jsfiddle.net/qdqrT/121/)

You can see on item #3 there is content in the .accordion-inner div but I do not want that displayed. Also you will see on item #4 there is no .accordion-inner inside #collapseFour which breaks the accordion completely.

Question 1: Is this possible with the Twitter Bootstrap accordion?

Question 2: Is there a better way of going about this process?

Code:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
        Collapsible Group Item #1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group Item #2
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        Anim pariatur cliche...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree">
        Collapsible Group Item #3
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        This is where i do not need child elements
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFour">
        Collapsible Group Item #4
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="accordion-body collapse">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/VXtQY/1/) I believe this is exactly what you are looking for.

just hide them using the proper functions.

```
$('#collapseFour').on('show', function () {
    $('#collapseFour').collapse('hide');
});

$('#collapseThree').on('show', function () {
    $('#collapseThree').collapse('hide');
});
```

Comment: thats where i was starting to lean.. just didnt want to add extra jQuery to the page..

Comment: There is already plenty of jQuery being used if you are using bootstrap. No harm in a few extra lines.

Comment: looks like im going with this.. i modified it a bit using a repeated class and this selector: http://jsfiddle.net/VXtQY/2/

Comment: No Need of jQuery to do a simple task like this. `Twitter Bootstrap` has the functionality to customize every aspect of it, then why use extra coding if The Bootstrap itself has a solution.

Comment: If the 'simple' task like this is included in the `Twitter Bootstrap` why is there no posted answer demonstrating such?? I can live with 2 lines of jQ..

Answer (score 0):

**Non- Jquery Solution**

Try this updated code [`here.`](http://jsfiddle.net/gr8_boi52/qdqrT/129/)

The 3rd accordion inner will not expand when clicked. And the shown accordion-inner will collapse.

Comment: thank you for your effort. that still expands the 3rd item which does not need to expand. all items 3 & 4 need to do is just collapse whatever accordion-inner is shown

Comment: getting closer.. now item 3 will not collapse the shown accordion-inner when clicked

Comment: I guess you didn't get what I was asking. Thank you for your effort, however, @Schmalzy came up with a better solution.

Comment: I have a no jquery solution... BTW @Schmalzy's solution did not work either because the shown accordion-inner still collapses

Comment: a "Non-jQuery Solution" which requires a jQuery function to operate.. you still do not understand what i am asking.. @Schmalzy wins, you lose..

Comment: I did not use any jQuery. It is fully functional non-jquery accordion

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind that it won't collapse the other areas when you click on it, you could just remove the  href="#collapseThree" element from the  tag

Comment: i do mind that it won't collapse.. clicking item 3 or 4 should collapse all.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, I added an attribute to tell the links to close all open tabs and used this jQuery function:

```
$('a[data-close]').click(function () {
    $($(this).data('parent')).find('.in').collapse('toggle');
});
```

This will give you the nice slide toggle effect.

Chek out **[the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qdqrT/130/)**

Comment: thank you, but that is too much extra weight for this solution.. this requires adding new data tags to all toggles and 114 characters of JQ as opposed to the original data dags and 60 characters of jQ suggested by @Schmalzy

Comment: I don't think it's any extra weight than your accepted solution, plus this provides a better UX. On your approach you added an extra class to the accordions that didn't need content plus you had to add the `.accordion-inner` to your last element, my solution only requires to add the attribute `data-close` to the links that you don't want to display any content, you can even keep all the current data attributes if you like, and no need to have the complete bootstrap markup.